# Between express server and react.js - fetch does not work?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, express

I am trying to get data in react by sending GET or POST request to express server.
But I can't receive response from server.

Below is my React component code.

```
    handleButton() {
        const sendData = {
            "say" : "Hello",
            "to" : "React App"
        };
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/", {
            mode : "no-cors",
            method : "POST",
            body : JSON.stringify(sendData)
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            alert(res);
        });
    }
```

**handleButton()** is called when I press the button.
I want to receive data from server when I click the button.

Then here is my express server code.

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer();
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("form");
});

app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", "./views");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

app.use(upload.array());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("received your request!");
});

app.listen(5000);
```

My server is very simple but it doesn't work.
When I press the button, server console outputs empty object.

This is my server console capture image.
[image]

And then this is my google chrome browser console capture image.

[image]

Please help me with getting right result. I want to notice that server received request by alert in react.

Comment: Have you tried setting the right Content-Type header?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner. How to set the right content-type header?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I tried like this : 
`headers : new Headers( {
         "Content-Type" : "application/json" } )`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works now.